# Copying text from file to specified Excel column

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I've got a text file, say, "`A.txt`" and an Excel file, say "`B.xlsx`". My goal is to copy all the text from `A.txt` to a specified column in `B.xlsx` using a python script. For example, let's say `A.txt` looks like:

```
Word1 5
Word2 Word3
6 Word4
```

I would then want to copy this into, say, column J in worksheet "Words", such that the contents of cell J1 are "`Word1 5`", the contents of J2 are "`Word2 Word3`", and so on...

So, to reformulate the question, how can I copy text from a specified text file and paste it into a specified Excel column, such that the content of each cell is equivalent to the content of each line (one-to-one relationship)?

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It sounds like you should take a look at [CSV Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). They can be opened in excel like regular documents but are editable in text editors. you can also script CSV manipulation in python by using the [CSV Module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html)

Comment: maybe you should rather try openpyxl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `win32com` library to interface directly with microsoft excel, as you are working in excel:

```
import win32com.client

#Read text file lines into list
f = open("A.txt")
text_contents = f.readlines()

# Open excel and your workbook
col = 2 # column B
excel=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible=True # Note: set to false when scripting, only True for this example
wb=excel.Workbooks.Open('B.xlsx')
ws = wb.Worksheets('Sheet1')

#Write text contents to column range
ws.Range(ws.Cells(col ,1),ws.Cells(col,len(text_contents))).Value = text_contents

#Save the workbook and quit
wb.Close(True)
excel.Application.Quit()
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error on the "wb.Save()" line - is there something I'm missing (I used precisely this code, changing only A.txt, B.xlsx and Sheet1)?

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I tried that as well and got the syntax error again - is it possible that it doesn't work due to the way wb is set up (sorry to keep pestering you with this)?

Comment: @RealFL the syntax error means it doesn't have anything to do with the call. After double checking, there was a missing right-paren in the range line. Try the edited code.

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it, thanks a lot for the help!