# read file content and write one of excel cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

Is there any way to write python script for

Read file content and write same in excel cell.

Example:
cat file.txt -->

This is file

above text content  need to be written in excel cell. Please suggest

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve here? I don't get it from your question. Can you give an example properly?

Comment: do you mean copy file contents and paste them in an excell cell?

Comment: first write the python script to read the file

Comment: Yes @virxen exactly

Comment: If possible, could you please share the code.

Comment: This should help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45225891/copying-text-from-file-to-specified-excel-column

Comment: if you want to get specific answer, then you have to share code.

Comment: I don't have code Deep Bhatt, I'm very new to python, I have files which has data, need to be paste data into one of excel cell.     Have to run this code in Linux machine

Answer (score 1):

**1)read file contents**

```
f=open("txt.txt","r",encoding="utf8")
a=f.readlines()
```

**2)send to excel cell**

```
from xlsxwriter import *
a="testing"
filename="test.xlsx"
wb = Workbook(filename)
sheet1 = wb.add_worksheet()
cell_format = wb.add_format({'bold': False})
cell_format.set_font_size(12)
sheet1.set_column(0, 0, 50, cell_format)
sheet1.write(0, 0, a)
wb.close()
```

**3) and as one program**

```
from xlsxwriter import *
f=open("txt.txt","r",encoding="utf8")
b=f.readlines()
a="".join(b)
filename="test.xlsx"
wb = Workbook(filename)
sheet1 = wb.add_worksheet()
cell_format = wb.add_format({'bold': False})
cell_format.set_font_size(12)
cell_format.set_text_wrap()
sheet1.set_column(0, 0, 50, cell_format)
sheet1.write(0, 0, a)
wb.close()
```

you need to install --> https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/

Comment: `from xlsxwriter import *
a="testing"
filename="test.xlsx"
wb = Workbook(filename)
sheet1 = wb.add_worksheet()
cell_format = wb.add_format({'bold': False})
cell_format.set_font_size(12)
sheet1.set_column(0, 0, 50, cell_format)
sheet1.write(0, 0, a)
wb.close()`


...



result will be "testing" in first column and row of excel, but you already set an value of  as "testing"

Comment: its 2 different codes.just combine them to one by removing a="testing"

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xlsxwriter/worksheet.py", line 503, in _write
    f = float(token)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: `readline() returns bracket `


might be this issue. ...its printing values as ['Hello']

Comment: `with open('txt.txt') as f:

    a = f.read()`

this works fine